# python bs4 extract from attribute inside button class

Tags: python, button, beautifulsoup

So im trying to get the value of a attribute using BeautifulSoup4.

```
replay_url_data = matchdatatr[1].findAll("button",{"class":"replay_button_super"})
```

This is how i get all my data into the object.
Typing the **replay_url_data** into the console returns :

```
<button class="replay_button_super" data-client-version="0.0.2.21" data-rel="spectatePopup" data-spectate-encryptionkey="bPPxpLIDmi0hRfU2U8B9Li1VJfTTx6pZ" data-spectate-endpoint="replays.cosmicradiance.com:80" data-spectate-gameid="4339075348" data-spectate-link="/api/spectate/UEJPNkN4MkIwUkZERUJ0MWUyZ3dDTmxGT25kanlUN2V6YnpuZUQ0bVlyMWRReGNDRXprZ1lQVnRnSkNHMG04Y2hUdVhxQm9abHFsQ2VBaTRaYVFPdnc9PQ==" data-spectate-platform="Modigu1" data-width="640"><i class="fa fa-play"></i>Replay</button>
```

What i want is to get the value of **data-spectate-link**.

I have tried every google result i found about similar topics but nothing worked.

```
replay_url_split = replay_url_data[0].findAll("button",{"class":"data-spectate-link"})
```

This returns "[]" empty.

```
replay_url_data[0].find('data-spectate-platform')
```

This returns same result empty

```
replay_url_data[0].find('button',attrs={'class' : 'data-spectate-link'})
```

And this one returns the same as above "[]" empty.

After 3 hours of searching on google so far nothing has helped me and im getting desperate.Im still new to python and  html so excuse my stupidity.

Comment: `findAll("button",{"class":"replay_button_super"})[0]["data-client-version"]`

Comment: @furas returns : TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: first I forgot `[0]` to get first item from list but now my comment has `[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get attribute you use `.attrs["data-spectate-link"]` or directly `["data-spectate-link"]`

---

Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

text = '<button class="replay_button_super" data-client-version="0.0.2.21" data-rel="spectatePopup" data-spectate-encryptionkey="bPPxpLIDmi0hRfU2U8B9Li1VJfTTx6pZ" data-spectate-endpoint="replays.cosmicradiance.com:80" data-spectate-gameid="4339075348" data-spectate-link="/api/spectate/UEJPNkN4MkIwUkZERUJ0MWUyZ3dDTmxGT25kanlUN2V6YnpuZUQ0bVlyMWRReGNDRXprZ1lQVnRnSkNHMG04Y2hUdVhxQm9abHFsQ2VBaTRaYVFPdnc9PQ==" data-spectate-platform="Modigu1" data-width="640"><i class="fa fa-play"></i>Replay</button>'
soup = BS(text, 'html.parser')

all_buttons = soup.findAll("button", {"class": "replay_button_super"})
one_button = all_buttons[0]

value = one_button["data-spectate-link"]
print(value)

value = one_button.attrs["data-spectate-link"]
print(value)
```

---

**BTW:** If you want to search buttons with attribute `data-spectate-link` then you have to search

```
{"data-spectate-link": True}
```

not `{"class": "data-spectate-link"}`

---

Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

text = '''<button>Other button</button>
<button>Other button</button>
<button>Other button</button>
<button class="replay_button_super" data-client-version="0.0.2.21" data-rel="spectatePopup" data-spectate-encryptionkey="bPPxpLIDmi0hRfU2U8B9Li1VJfTTx6pZ" data-spectate-endpoint="replays.cosmicradiance.com:80" data-spectate-gameid="4339075348" data-spectate-link="/api/spectate/UEJPNkN4MkIwUkZERUJ0MWUyZ3dDTmxGT25kanlUN2V6YnpuZUQ0bVlyMWRReGNDRXprZ1lQVnRnSkNHMG04Y2hUdVhxQm9abHFsQ2VBaTRaYVFPdnc9PQ==" data-spectate-platform="Modigu1" data-width="640"><i class="fa fa-play"></i>Replay</button>
<button>Other button</button>
<button>Other button</button>'''

soup = BS(text, 'html.parser')

all_buttons = soup.findAll("button", {"data-spectate-link": True})
one_button = all_buttons[0]

value = one_button["data-spectate-link"]
print(value)
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked.I dont know why i couldnt find any information similar to what you have gave me.

Comment: people mostly search by `class` or `id` and later they get `text` or `href`/`src` - so examples with other attributes can be very rare. I think that even in [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) it is hard to find it.

Answer (score 0):

```
soup.button['data-spectate-link']
```

is what you want.

`soup.button` set the tag inside the soup. Then with `['data-spectate-link']` you can set property inside the tag.

[docs here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Answer (score 0):

`data-spectate-link` is an attribute.To get the value of `data-spectate-link` you need to use `element['data-spectate-link']`

You can use either `findAll`() or CSS selector `select`()

```
replay_url_data =matchdatatr[1].findAll("button",attrs={"class" :"replay_button_super", "data-spectate-link" :True})
print(replay_url_data[0]['data-spectate-link'])
```

OR Css selector

```
replay_url_data =soup.select("button.replay_button_super[data-spectate-link]")
print(replay_url_data[0]['data-spectate-link'])
```

Comment: Just tried your code , it works too! But i already marked the first answer as "answer".